# How to not have time be a bind parameter in SQL, but have a parameter be bound?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I wish to select orders from after 23:00:00 but have a prompt for date selection, but when I use bind parameters the time is recognised as a parameter for binding since it contains ":", what is a workaround for this? I need just `OrderDate` to be a bind parameter.

```
WHERE TimeOfOrder >'23:00:00' AND DateOfOrder = :OrderDate;
```

[Screenshot showing bind parameters ":00" and ":OrderDate"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl82y.png)

Comment: Which environment is this? Poorly parsed...

Comment: Apologies, this is phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using CAST(" ") for the time stopped the environment from seeing 23:00:00 as a possible bind parameter.

```
WHERE DateOfOrder =':OrderDate' AND TimeOfOrder >=CAST("230000" AS TIME)
```